Prove that If $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)>0$, then there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{x^2f'(x)f'(0)}{f(x)^2} < 1$.

Prove that If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an analytic function such that $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)>0$, then there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\frac{x^2f'(x)f'(0)}{f(x)^2} < 1$$

I have tried to differentiate this equation, but it requires the information of $f'''(x)$ to continue the argument. Also, since equality holds when $f(x)=x$, I consider the following two cases: $f(x)$ converges to a line, and otherwise.
For the first case, $f(x)/x$ and $f'(x)$ converge to the slope of this line as $x\to\infty$ and $f'(0)<f'(x)$ when $x>0$ and this completes the proof.
For the second case, my claim is $f(x)^2$ grows much faster than $x^2f'(x)$ and $x^2f(x)f'(0)/{f(x)^2}\to0$ as $x\to \infty$. But I have no idea to prove this rigorously. Do you have an idea for this problem?

Clearly, if $f(0) \neq 0$, then $x = 0$ fits the bill. So, we assume $f(0) = 0$. Note, since $f'(x) > 0$, we have $f'(x) \neq 0$ for $x \neq 0$.
Define, on $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$,
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{f'(0)}{f(x)}.$$
Then
$$g'(x) = \frac{f'(0)f'(x)}{f(x)^2} - \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{x^2f'(0)f'(x)}{f(x)^2} - 1\right).$$
As such, what we wish to prove is equivalent to asserting $g'(x) \le 0$ for some $x \neq 0$.
Note that $f$ is strictly convex, and hence it is minorised by its tangent at $x = 0$, which is$$y = f'(0)x + f(0) = f'(0)x,$$
which is to say,
$$f'(0)x \le f(x) \implies \frac{f'(0)}{f(x)} \le \frac{1}{x} \implies g(x) \ge 0$$
for $x > 0$. Since $f$ is strictly convex, the tangent will only touch the graph at the point $x = 0$, implying that $g(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$. Moreover,
$$0 \le \frac{f'(0)}{f(x)} \le \frac{1}{x} \to 0$$
as $x \to \infty$, hence $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.
From here, the solution is relatively clear: as $g$ approaches its infimum as $x \to \infty$, it cannot be strictly increasing for all $x$. If it were, we would have $g(x) > g(1) > 0$ for $x > 1$, so $g(x)$ could not possibly converge to $0$. Thus, $g(x) \le 0$ for some $x > 0$, and we are done.

If you're wondering where the $g$ comes from, I treated the functional inequality as an equality, and tried solving the differential equation by separation of variables. After separating and integrating, you get $-\frac{f'(0)}{f(x)} = -\frac{1}{x} + C$. Rearranging gets me the inspiration for defining $g$ in this way.
